# using eigenvector centrality for weighted graph in python

Tags: python, graph, similarity, eigenvector, central

I want to use network centrality to a similarity matrix. It means that I have a similarity matrix as below:

```
similarity matrix:[[1,0.1,1,0.4],
                   [0.13,1,0.9,0.6],
                   [0.6,0.1,1,0.11],
                   [0.5,0.23,0.43,1]]
```

Then I created a weighted graph for this matrix. But I don't know how can I create eigenvector centrality for this graph. I used from below code to do this:

```
centrality = nx.eigenvector_centrality_numpy(G, weight='weight')
```

But can anybody help me to know what means weight in this code? what should I replace instead of it? my graph is weighted by itself. How can I show it in this code?

Answer (score 0):

So if you created the graph in the following way:

```
G = nx.from_numpy_array(sim_matrix)
```

then the graph is weighted by default with your weights. Each edge has an attribute 'weight'. You can test it by running the following code:

```
G.edges(data=True)

EdgeDataView([(0, 0, {'weight': 1.0}), (0, 1, {'weight': 0.13}), (0, 2, {'weight': 0.6}), (0, 3, {'weight': 0.5}), (1, 1, {'weight': 1.0}), (1, 2, {'weight': 0.1}), (1, 3, {'weight': 0.23}), (2, 2, {'weight': 1.0}), (2, 3, {'weight': 0.43}), (3, 3, {'weight': 1.0})])
```

You can define different attributes to each edge/node 
[see networkx documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.0/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_edge_attributes.html)

Therefore when you use eigenvector_centrality_numpy you can define the attribute for the weight. In your case it 'weight' which also a default in [documentation](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.eigenvector_centrality_numpy.html).